# Changing label in auth.User model field

Tags: django, django-models

How to change label for `User` field, e.g. for `username`? I'm using `CustomUser` model that inherits `AbstractUser`, and I want to change `label` for some fields.
I try do next in `CustomUser` model, but it's not working. Any ideas?

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUser,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.username.__setattr__('label', 'Some text')
```

Answer (score 1):

A Django model's fields are moved to `Model._meta` at class initialization, since Django 1.8, you can access them using the [_meta API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/models/meta/).

Also, `label` is an attribute of form fields, the equivalent for model fields is `verbose_name`.

This should work an Django 1.8

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUser,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta.get_field('username').verbose_name = 'Some text'
```

Before Django 1.8 you can use `self._meta.get_field_by_name('username')[0]` instead of `self._meta.get_field('username')`.